# getting a bufferedImage from a bytearray

Tags: java, image, arrays, bufferedimage

I am trying to get back a `bufferedImage` from `array of bytes`, but I am getting an error saying `bufferedimage is null`. I actually tried several ways, everything ended up in the same way. Here goes my code:

1)

```
 byte[] arr = Base64.decode(base64String);
 BufferedImage bImageFromConvert =ImageIO.read(new  ByteArrayInputStream(arr));
```

2)

```
 InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
 BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

I am pretty sure my byte array contains data and I think `ImageIO.read()` is where my code goes wrong.

Comment: What do you mean `pretty sure`? Have you tried logging the length of the array?

Comment: i tried printing the byte array

Comment: Can you post the code of how you convert the image to a Base64String?

Comment: <code>' BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("G:\\a.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String base64String=Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray()); '</code>

Comment: What is the package name of the Base64 library you are using?

Comment: import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your `BufferedImage` to `Base64` encode method as you have posted in the comments.

You are never writing the `BufferedImage` to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Therefore the Base64 string is empty, and reading the empty string produces a `null` `BufferedImage`.

You should use this code to encode your image:

```
 BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("G:\\a.jpg"));
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ImageIO.write( originalImage, "jpg", baos );
 String base64String=Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
```

To decode the image use this code:

```
 byte[] arr = Base64.decode(base64String);
 BufferedImage bImageFromConvert =ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(arr));
 System.out.println(bImageFromConvert.getWidth());
```

Comment: Actually, it would be better (as in faster, use less memory *and* look better) to just Base64 encode the contents of `a.jpg` directly (just read the contents into a `byte` array), rather than using `ImageIO` to re-encode the JPEG into a byte array. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.Maybe it works. It worked for me.

```
byte[] aByteArray = {};
    int width = ;
    int height = ;

    DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(aByteArray, aByteArray.length);

    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, 3 * width, 3, new int[] {0, 1, 2}, (Point)null);
    ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorModel.getRGBdefault().getColorSpace(), false, true, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE); 
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, true, null);
```

Just add the byte, width and height to code and customize it.

Comment: i am so dumb, how to get the width and height

Comment: you shouldn't get it. you should add what you want to be.